# AuthorizeNet CIM gateway in Commerce 1

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there any barrier to using AuthorizeNet CIM gateway in Commerce 1? The vendor/omnipay/authorizenet folder has a CIMGateway class but there doesn't appear to be a corresponding AuthorizeNet_CIM_GatewayAdapter. I'm wondering why it's not supported by default, and how difficult it would be to implement it for a client.

Answer (score 1):

This Authorize.Net Accept.js gateway for Craft Commerce might be a good place to start: https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-acceptjs